# Trouble redirecting the page after deletion of the entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have this entry that I am trying to delete from the index page where all the entries are listed in rails 4.

**controller code:**

```
  def destroy
    @entry.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html{ redirect_to :action => :index}
     end
  end
```

**View code:**

```
  <%entry ||= Entry.new(:date => Time.new)
   id = dom_id entry%>
     -SOME-CODE-IN-HERE

  <%= link_to image_tag("delete.png"),  {:action => :destroy, :id => entry},
 data:{:confirm => "Are you sure to delete this entry?"}, method: 
:delete, remote: true %>
```

When I click on the delete image the entry is getting deleted from the database  but the page does not refresh.It still shows the old deleted entry till the page is refreshed manually. Could some on  please help me to automatically redirect the page to index after the entry is deleted. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want to get with `%Q{ $('##{dom_id(@entry)}').remove()`

Comment: the delete action is being called twice. The first time delete action is called it is successfully executed and after that the delete action is called for the second time again which says " ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/sheet_entries"):"

Comment: You could remove the `remote: true` if you want a page reload, otherwise you should have to "hide" from the DOM the record you've deleted.

Comment: Thanks !!! removing the remote:true helped..!!!

Comment: Could you update your question to make an answer?, it seems it lacks the path in the link_to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem that you are having is you are making a remote call to the server with `remote: true` this makes a ajax call and does not bind it back to the browser.

```
<%= link_to image_tag("delete.png"),  {:action => :destroy, :id => entry}, data:{:confirm => "Are you sure to delete this entry?"}, method: :delete %>
```

You can read more about [remote-elements](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#link-to)